# Can I generate a private key with pyOpenSSL with a passphrase

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl, passphrase

I am using pyOpenSSL to generate CSR's in mass.

I need to generate a private key file that is passphrase protected.

Code snippet:

```
key = crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(type, bits)
f = open(_keyfile, "w"
f.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key))
f.close()
```

I can't find anywhere in the docs that confirms whther or not I can generate a key with a passphrase.

If I was using openssl on the command line I would do the following:

```
${OPENSSLCMD} req -new -newkey rsa:"${KEYSIZE}" -passout pass:"${DBPASS}" -out "${DBFILE}" -keyout "${DBKEYFILE}" -subj "${CERTDN}" -config "${OPENSSLCONFIG}"
```

Is there a way to use pyOpenSSL to add a passphrase to a key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far from the answer. To export the key you wrote:

```
f.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key))
```

As the [`OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey`](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey) function accepts an optional argument `passphrase`, you could just do this:

```
f.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key, passphrase='your_passphrase_here'))
```

**EDITED:**

> I can't find anywhere in the docs that confirms whther or not I can generate a key with a passphrase.

Just to clarify that a passphras is not involved when *generating* a key, however it is when *exporting* the key. Also whenever you load the key using [`OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey`](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey) the same passphrase is required.